# How does for loop impact performance of spark code

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark

I have two piece of codes below having same logic, curious to know which one is better of two and why?

1.

```
char_list = [('\\\\', '\\\\\\\\'), ('\n', '\\\\n'), ('\'', '\\\\\'')]
col_names = df.schema.names
df.select( *[func.regexp_replace(col_name, char_set[0], char_set[1]) for char_set in char_list for col_name in col_names])
```

2. 

```
char_list = [('\\\\', '\\\\\\\\'), ('\n', '\\\\n'), ('\'', '\\\\\'')]
col_names = df.schema.names
for char_set in char_list:
    for col_name in col_names:
        df = df.withColumn(col_name, func.regexp_replace(col_name, char_set[0], char_set[1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the two codes are not the same. The second code should be what you wanted. In the first code you selected duplicated columns because `select` does not overwrite columns, but `withColumn` does.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

char_list = [('\\\\', '\\\\\\\\'), ('\n', '\\\\n'), ('\'', '\\\\\'')]
col_names = df.schema.names

df = spark.createDataFrame([['1','2']])
print(len(df.select( *[func.regexp_replace(col_name, char_set[0], char_set[1]) for char_set in char_list for col_name in col_names]).columns))
# gives 6

df = spark.createDataFrame([['1','2']])
for char_set in char_list:
    for col_name in col_names:
        df = df.withColumn(col_name, func.regexp_replace(col_name, char_set[0], char_set[1]))

print(len(df.columns))
# gives 2
```

Comment: May i know in the second code for loop executes on the driver or executor.

I am under the assumption that for loop written as part of select statement gets executed on the executor. Am in correct?

Comment: Nothing is executed due to lazy evaluation. The code only includes transformations, but not actions. Only a query plan is created.

Comment: You can do `df.explain()` to check the query plan.

Comment: may i know if the second code is efficient or is there any other way?